# MongoDb error: cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled

Tags: java, mongodb

I was using mongo in dev just fine, when deploying the app into test env I got this error when objects are saved in the application

```
cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled
```

Dispatcher servlet is the same for both applications (dev vs test) with JOURNAL_SAFE 

What did I do wrong?

```
    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" write-concern="JOURNAL_SAFE">
    <mongo:options connections-per-host="50"
               threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="4"
               connect-timeout="1000"
               max-wait-time="1500"
               auto-connect-retry="true"
               socket-keep-alive="true"
               socket-timeout="1500"
               slave-ok="true"
               write-number="1"
               write-timeout="0"
               write-fsync="false"/>
</mongo:mongo>
```

Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.CommandFailureException: { "serverUsed" : "127.0.0.1:27017" , "ok" : 0 , "code" : 2 , "errmsg" : "cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled"} 
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.getException(CommandResult.java:76) 
    at com.mongodb.CommandResult.throwOnError(CommandResult.java:131) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl$3.execute(DBCollectionImpl.java:498) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl$3.execute(DBCollectionImpl.java:491) 
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.doOperation(DBTCPConnector.java:210) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.receiveWriteCommandMessage(DBCollectionImpl.java:491) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.writeWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:430) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.updateWithCommandProtocol(DBCollectionImpl.java:417) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.update(DBCollectionImpl.java:267) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:191) 
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:224) 
    at com.xerox.dao.MainDaoImpl.saveOrUpdatePrinter(MainDaoImpl.java:246) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) 
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155) 
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: There is a reason for this behavior: if the code aka the business logic expects that operations are journaled, it is a good thing to know that this requirement can't be met.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was a change in 2.6. The MongoDB server now requires that journaling be enabled to use a write concern that has journaling as a requirement. In 2.4 and before the server would silently ignore the journal requirement is journaling was not enabled on the server.

You test MongoDB cluster must have journaling disabled. Either enable journaling on the server or remove the default write concern on the client (e.g., remove/change write-concern="JOURNAL_SAFE"). For production, you almost definitely want journaling enabled.

If you are using a replica set (or a shared cluster of replica sets) with at least 3 data holding members then a write concern of 'majority' might be a better, more performant, choice. (e.g., write-concern="MAJORITY" ).

If you are running a single Mongod process that is not part of a replica-set then you probably want a journal write concern but need to make sure that the journal is not disabled on the server. If you cannot control the server (and are still using a single mongod process) then you might want to switch to the FSYNC write concern. With FSYNC if the server has journaling enabled then it acts as a Journaled write, for a server without journaling enabled it will force all of the data files to disk (which will cause a lot of latency). Having said that you are better off getting journaling enabled on the server.

Rob.

Comment: so for single instance of mongodb in prod, what should this write-concern be?

Comment: @user648026: that _heavily_ depends on your data and your requirements. For 'cheap' data like clickstreams and caching data and such, you usually can use something like 'unacknowledged'. If the data is more valuable, you want to have it in the journal at least. If you want to make sure that the data is persistent even if one node fails, you should have a write concern of `w:majority` or `w:2`. If you have a read preference including secondaries and need to be absolutely positively sure that after the write returns all reads on all nodes return the same values, you _may_ set `w:all`.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting this here in hopes someone else will find this helpful since it helped me.

I wanted to run mongock for production purposes but it kept failing all my unit tests.

I kept getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionDriver' defined in class path resource [io/mongock/driver/mongodb/springdata/v3/config/SpringDataMongoV3Context.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.mongock.driver.api.driver.ConnectionDriver]: Factory method 'connectionDriver' threw exception; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled' on server localhost:52663. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "cannot use 'j' option when a host does not have journaling enabled", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}
```

The solution was to add this flag in the application-test.properties:

```
mongock.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 0):

For the one using Spring Boot, I would avoid deactivating mongock because your mongo db is not sync with prod anymore.

You can create your own **EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration** and add the journal in it.

Personally, I used this one with Spring Boot 2.7 :

```
@Configuration
public class MyEmbeddedMongoConfiguration extends EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration {

    private final MongoProperties properties;

    private static final byte[] IP4_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS = new byte[]{127, 0, 0, 1};
    private static final byte[] IP6_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS = new byte[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};

    public MyEmbeddedMongoConfiguration(MongoProperties properties) {
        super(properties);
        this.properties=properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongodConfig embeddedMongoConfiguration(EmbeddedMongoProperties embeddedProperties) throws IOException {
        ImmutableMongodConfig.Builder builder = MongodConfig.builder()
                .version(Version.V4_0_12)
                .cmdOptions(MongoCmdOptions.builder().useNoJournal(false).build());
        EmbeddedMongoProperties.Storage storage = embeddedProperties.getStorage();
        if (storage != null) {
            String databaseDir = storage.getDatabaseDir();
            String replSetName = storage.getReplSetName();
            int oplogSize = storage.getOplogSize() != null ? (int)storage.getOplogSize().toMegabytes() : 0;
            builder.replication(new de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.Storage(databaseDir, replSetName, oplogSize));
        }

        Integer configuredPort = this.properties.getPort();
        if (configuredPort != null && configuredPort > 0) {
            builder.net(new Net(this.getHost().getHostAddress(), configuredPort, Network.localhostIsIPv6()));
        } else {
            builder.net(new Net(this.getHost().getHostAddress(), Network.freeServerPort(this.getHost()), Network.localhostIsIPv6()));
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private InetAddress getHost() throws UnknownHostException {
        return this.properties.getHost() == null ? InetAddress.getByAddress(Network.localhostIsIPv6() ? IP6_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS : IP4_LOOPBACK_ADDRESS) : InetAddress.getByName(this.properties.getHost());
    }
}
```

The important part :

```
  ImmutableMongodConfig.Builder builder = MongodConfig.builder()
                .version(Version.V4_0_12).cmdOptions(MongoCmdOptions.builder().useNoJournal(false).build());
```

This code is adapted from the Spring Boot Configuration **EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration**. Look for the method **embeddedMongoConfiguration** if you need to do it.